# QUIC in Catchpoint - Can we add Chromium flags to enable QUIC in catchpoint?

Tags: flags, quic

I am trying to run some performance tests to visualize the benefits of QUIC on catchpoint. Any thoughts on how to test QUIC on catchpoint? I know curl allow Chromium flags. Is there a way to add flags in the script or the CP UI?